# installing parse dashboard on amazon aws elastic beanstalk (or locally?)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been following [this](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)
guide to installing Parse Server on Amazon AWS with Elastic Beanstalk, and the set up is working fine, however that particular guide only addresses the installation of Parse Server and not the Parse Dashboard, which I would also like to have set up.

Being as Parse is a Node.js app, I was hoping I could get away with "npm install -g parse-dashboard" through the command line, but seeing as the changes on the instance might be overwritten by the load balancer I am not sure this is the right path.

I do know that Amazon has an EB CLI that can be used to install applications but I am not sure if that is the best/simplest way either?

What I would like is the easiest way to install Parse Dashboard and connect it with my AWS EB set-up, and I would also like for the Parse Dashboard to be easily updated when changes are made available through Github.

So my question really boils down to two alternatives, as I see it;

1) Should I install the Parse Dashboard on AWS, if so - what would be the best way to do this?

2) Can I perhaps set up a local install of the Parse Dashboard and connect it to my Parse Server hosted on AWS EB? If so, what would be the recommended method of doing this.

Comment: I found the answer to my second question [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) but I would still like help with answering the first question, what would be the best way to install parse dashboard on Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, you don't want to put the dashboard in public domain. Parse dashboard gives full access to modify your database.

If you still want to do it, it can be done just like the parse-server. Once you have clone the repository add an `app.config` file under `/your_project_folder/.ebextensions/app.config` with the following content:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "npm start"
```

and then follow this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep Parse installed locally then :)

Comment: I'm going to try the dashboard and currently beanstalk doesn't even deploy the server because of some dashboard related error. I wanted to try your solution however, I don't have a .ebextensions folder. Just a .elasticbeanstalk folder which is hidden but there. Should I just put that app.config under there?